# Is there a way to install perl module upon installation of Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to install Perl locally (without internet). Some of my working codes needs to add some modules to make it work (for fresh installed perl). But in my case, i can't install the modules because i don't have internet connection.

Is it possible to install Perl locally with a module like Text::CSV?

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most distributions, the `CPAN` module and `cpan` app downloads the distribution from a CPAN mirror site, unpacks it into a directory, and runs some standard set of commands like

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

If you can workaround the download-from-the-internet step (say, by copying the distributions to a CD/DVD/USB drive), you can do the other steps manually. Don't forget to include the distributions for dependencies of the modules you are interested in (`Text::CSV`, for example, depends on `IO::Handle`, `Test::More`, and `Test::Harness` [though those are pretty standard modules]).

Comment: just a follow up question, how could i run the commands 'make, make test, make install' in windows xp? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: quinekxi, better [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and ask there again.

Comment: @quinekxi - if you have Strawberry Perl, it's `dmake` instead of `make`. For Active Perl it might be `nmake`.

Comment: @socketpuppet - oh, sorry, i forgot to include what perl i used. Thats why make command doesn't work on me. Thanks for your follow up answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the make dance (`perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install`), use the make reported by `perl -V:make` or use  `cpan Text::xSV` or `cpanp i Text::xSV`

See [Installing Modules](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=546527) / `perldoc [perlmodinstall]`

Regarding building your own perl see [Building your own "Strawberry Perl Plus..."] on the strawberryperl website

What you probably want, the simplest solution, is  to download a "relocatable" perl, a portable perl,  like http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.12.3.0/strawberry-perl-5.12.3.0-portable.zip

And fill with all the modules you need, and take it with you on a usb drive